# Processing a single column at a time instead of keeping the whole data in memory in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I have a large dataset in redshift(~ 3 million rows and 1500 columns). Currently I am pulling all the data and doing some data processing like
missing value imputations and creating dummies etc. I do it on each column by looping through column names. This consumes a lot of memory because of the 
data size since I keep the whole data in a dataframe till the processing is done.

I am thinking of storing the data in a csv and then read in each column , do the data processing and write the processed column to a csv.

Data

```
sv_m1   rev     ioip    dvr_m1  geo
0       15.31   40      0       NJN
0       64.9    0       0       CT
0       18.36   20      0       AX
0       62.85   0       0       AL
0       10.31   20      0       BS
0       12.84   10      13.95   MN
0       69.95   0       0       CT
0       32.81   20      13.95   FX
```

So say my csv which has all the data is : seg_data.csv

I want to read in the first column, do the processing and write it to another csv - final_seg.csv.
Then I want to do the same for the next column and the next and similarly for all the columns.
The data processing might involve creating dummies if the variable is categorical like geo.
I maintain a mapping of variable name and type in a separate csv which I load into a dict (attribute_dict).

Below is what I am doing currently after reading in the data from DB and storing it in df_data_sample.

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame()
for column in df_data_sample.columns:
        df_column = df_data_sample[[column]]
        if (((attribute_dict[column] == 'CAT') & (df_column[column].unique().size < 100))==True):
            df_target_attribute = pd.get_dummies(df_column[column], dummy_na=True, prefix=column)
            df_target_attribute.fillna(0) 
            df_final[target_column] = df_target_attribute[[target_column]]


        elif (attribute_dict[column] == 'NUM'):
            #Let's impute with 0 for numeric variables:
            df_target_attribute = df_column
            df_target_attribute.fillna(value=0,inplace=True)
            df_final[column] = df_target_attribute
```

So basically I do not want to keep df_data_sample in memory and load just one column at a time,process it, write the processed column(if numeric),
and columns(dummies if categorical) into another csv. This should happen for all columns.

Expected output csv

```
sv_m1   rev     ioip    dvr_m1  geo_NJN geo_CT  geo_AX geo_BS   
0       15.31   40      0       1       0       0       0
0       64.9    0       0       0       1       0       0
0       18.36   20      0       0       0       1       0
0       62.85   0       0       1       0       0       0
0       10.31   20      0       0       0       0       1
0       12.84   10      13.95   0       0       1       0
0       69.95   0       0       0       1       0       0
0       32.81   20      13.95   0       0       0       1
```

I am thinking that since I keep only 1 column at a time in memory, this will reduce my memory usage(currently goes to 75% on server).

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `usecols` parameter in `read_csv` will help you achieve this. The way I would do this is I would keep loading subsets of the data over and over -

```
cols = ["sv_m1","rev","ioip","dvr_m1","geo_NJN","geo_CT","geo_AX","geo_BS"]
for col in cols:
    df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', usecols=[col])
    print(df)
```

Instead of `print(df)`, obviously you would do your processing with that column.

You can use `if/else` to cater to different processing for different columns.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

reading csv files is slow, if your original data is from csv files, you can read the csv files in chuck, and append it to a hdf5 file by using `to_hdf(..., append=True)`. Then read the the column by `pd.read_hdf(..., columns=[...])`.